# I need to extract the every 2nd line from the matched pattern from a given file in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having a below lines in a file

```
name
place
time
create
delete
time
update
modify
time
teach
lesson
chapter
section
time
source
code
them
time
view
print
kill
```

My requirement is, I need to match the word "time" from that line i need to extract the every 2nd line from the file.Also i may have n number of lines after "time" pattern in the file but only print the exact second line from that
   Output look like

```
delete
modify
lesson
code
print
```

How i done this in ruby?

```
n=0
f = File.open("30.txt")
f.each do |line|
    n=n+1
    if line=~/time/
        puts "#{n}: #{line}"
    end
end
f.close
```

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is not a coding or tutoring service. Show your code. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to get this right. The trick is having two states, one where you're looking for the "time" string in the line, and another when you've found it and you've kept track of what line that appeared on:

```
time_line = nil

DATA.readlines.each_with_index do |line, i|
  if time_line and ((i - time_line) % 2) == 0
    # n % 2 == 0 only triggers on even lines.
    puts line
  else
    if line.match(/time/)
      time_line = i
    end
  end
end

# This shows up as DATA, but you can use $stdin or another File just the same
__END__
name
place
time
create
delete
time
update
modify
time
teach
lesson
time
source
code
time
view
print
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I have edited the question now. I may have n number of lines after "time"  word but i need to extract only the second from that

Comment: Well, this produces the desired output, so hopefully you can adapt it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
words = File.readlines("30.txt")
puts words.to_enum.with_index.collect{|word, i| word =~ /^time/ ? words[i+2] : nil}.compact
```

This results in the desired output:

```
delete
modify
lesson
code
print
```

Explanation:

- `words` is an array of lines from the file.
- I want to use `with_index` but that only works on Enumerators so I had to call `to_enum` on the array.
- `with_index` allows me to `collect` the instances of the word "time" and then get the word at the index + 2
- `compact` gets rid of the empty lines from non-matches.

I came up with this hastily, it may be able to be shortened further.